# write data to local text file from live site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, streamwriter

My question isn't necessarily how to write to a text file but, once my website is on the web hosts server, will the data still be written to the text file on my computer. I am currently working in Visual Web Developer and I am debugging in my machines localhost server. So right now there is no question that it will be written to the file on my computer but, once the site is live on another server and a different computer goes to the site, is it going to try to write to their computer?

Here is my code, I am simply looking for a little information and whether my code will need to change when I upload to a different server. I am trying to write paypal transaction details to a text file on my computer. Whenever someone purchases something from my website I need to get the data. It needs to be written in the text file that is on my computer and my computer only, not the actual user who purchased something.

Is this possible or am I going about this the wrong way and need to do something different?

```
Dim objfirst As New StreamWriter("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Sales Orders.txt", True)
For i As Integer = 1 To results("num_cart_items")
    objfirst.Write(results("first_name") + " " + results("last_name") + ", ")
    objfirst.Write(results("business").Replace("+", " ") & ", "
    objfirst.Write(results("address_street").Replace("+", " ") & ", " & results("address_city").Replace("+", " ") & ", " & results("address_state").Replace("+", " ") & ", " & results("address_zip") + ", ")

    objfirst.Write(results("payer_email").Replace("%40", "@") & ", ")
    objfirst.Write(results("item_name" & i).Replace("+", " ") + ", ")
    objfirst.Write(results("item_number" & i).Replace("+", "") + ", ")
    objfirst.Write(results("quantity" & i) + ", ")
    objfirst.Write(results("mc_gross_" & i))
    objfirst.WriteLine()
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What if they/your server (not really sure I understand) don't have the directory "C:\Users\User\Desktop\"? Use Environment variables.

Comment: Ok, Sorry about that lesson learned, thank you. Any comments pertaining the actual question???

Comment: I'm wanting to have it write to a file on my computer and my computer only. I'm not sure but it seems like using the code I have now, it will try to write it to the users computer. I want it to get written to my computer only know matter who is on the site.

Comment: I edited my question and gave a little further reasoning in my question, It's something dealing with paypal transactions.

Comment: The above code will write the file always on the web server

Comment: Sorry that I don't completely understand @sgk. By saying always write the file on the web server, does this mean it will write to a file that is uploaded on the web server, or that it will write to the file that is saved on my computer or something else

Comment: ok, the above code gets executed on the web server that hosts its. It could be your local machine or any other machine. When a client connects to your web site and when this function is executed, the function will write the file to the path you have mentioned on the server. i.e the file will not be written to client's machine unless you push it via http response.

Comment: So are you saying that I can specify from my web host account the path to my file or is it automatically recognizing that the file path above is on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in question saves the file to the web server it's running on. It's saving on your computer now because your computer *is the web server*.

When you move the code to a 'real' web server, that's where the files will be saved, instead, with that code. They will *not* be saved to your personal computer, or any user's computer. Only on the server itself.

---

If you need the files to be 'sent' to you, you will need to look into a way to do that. EMail, a database, or a private area of the site where you can browse and view the files are your options. (more info on those is beyond the scope of things here)

One additional detail I have to mention: You need to make *very sure* that public users will have no access to the uploaded files. If you are running on a server with ASP.NET (including MVC), the `App_Data` folder is a good place, since by default, web requests cannot be made for files there. You'd then create code to view them separately. (Again; details on this are beyond the scope of this)